# Не работает https на nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, windows-10, ssl

```js
2023/07/17 21:18:08 [notice] 17472#19384: signal process started
2023/07/17 21:18:17 [notice] 18560#3444: signal process started
2023/07/17 21:31:42 [notice] 13628#3180: signal process started
2023/07/17 21:34:40 [notice] 8636#21436: signal process started
2023/07/17 22:01:02 [notice] 7140#17252: signal process started
2023/07/18 19:08:37 [emerg] 7660#8960: "location" directive is not allowed here in C:\nginx-1.25.1/conf/nginx.conf:29
```

Есть сервер на своём ПК на Windows 10 x64, работает через nginx+node.js. Решил себе установить сертификат через Certbot,вот такой вышел файл конфигурации nginx:

```js
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name auto8.pp.ua;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name auto8.pp.ua;

        ssl_certificate     C:/nginx-1.25.1/ssl/fullchain4.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key C:/nginx-1.25.1/ssl/privkey4.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.199:3001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root html;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот настройки брандмауера, роутера,проверка портов перед запуском сервера[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: брандмауер][image: роутер]

вот код index.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const authRouter = require('./authRouter');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/auth", authRouter);
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

const start = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://Start01:2587174728@cluster0.vnlcbha.mongodb.net/Automobiles?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
            exec('start https://auto8.pp.ua/index.html', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(`Error opening browser: ${error}`);
                }
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Сервер запущен на порту 3001');
});
start();
```

код auth.js:

```js
const registrationForm = document.getElementById('registrationForm');
const loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');

registrationForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = registrationForm.elements.username.value;
    const password = registrationForm.elements.password.value;

    fetch('https://auto8.pp.ua/auth/registration', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            // Вывод сообщения об успешной регистрации или обработка ошибки
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            // Обработка ошибки
        });
});

loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = loginForm.elements.username.value;
    const password = loginForm.elements.password.value;

    fetch('https://auto8.pp.ua/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            // Вывод токена аутентификации или обработка ошибки
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            // Обработка ошибки
        });
});
```

вот какие файлы у меня есть по сертификату: [image: сертификаты]

При http:// авторизация работает, но когда я провожу авторизацию через https:// то такие ошибки в консоли: «auth.js:32 POST https://auto8.pp.ua/auth/login net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
(anonymous) @ auth.js:32
auth.js:45 TypeError: Failed to fetch
at HTMLFormElement. (auth.js:32:5)». Вопрос в том: **как мне настроить ssl сертификат через certbot на windows 10 чтобы сайт работал на https:// и что мне поменять в файле конфигурации, что я не так  сделал?**
error.log

Comment: a) судя по настройкам роутера в nginx запросы вообще не доходят. б) в вашем примере сервер на ноде слушает порт 3000, а перенаправляете запросы вы в 3001. в) вывод netstat бесполезный. Вам нужно посмотреть какие порты слушаются, что-то типа `netstat -nlt`.

Comment: Отдельно стоит проверить конфиг nginx командой `nginx -t`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, по поводу роутера: как там нужно правильно прописать? (просто через http я могу зайти на сайт откуда угодно из интернета), б) если поставить там на 3001 то в ноде ошибка что порт уже занят: "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3001 ", конфиг проверил, показывает: "C:\nginx-1.25.1>nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file C:\nginx-1.25.1/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file C:\nginx-1.25.1/conf/nginx.conf test is successful"

Comment: @AlexeyTen ">> netstat -ano | findstr :80
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       13472
  TCP    192.168.0.199:49766    192.168.0.200:8008     ESTABLISHED     13248
  TCP    192.168.0.199:49776    192.168.0.200:8009     ESTABLISHED     13248
  TCP    192.168.0.199:50168    192.168.0.200:8009     ESTABLISHED     10348
  TCP    192.168.0.199:55137    216.58.215.67:80       ESTABLISHED     10348
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       13472"

Comment: @AlexeyTen >> netstat -ano | findstr :443
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       13472
  TCP    192.168.0.199:49681    20.199.120.85:443      ESTABLISHED     6224
  
  TCP    [::]:443               [::]:0                 LISTENING       13472
  UDP    127.0.0.1:44301        *:*                                    6184

Comment: @AlexeyTen , какие настройки в роутере прописать можете подсказать? Я так понял при правильном пробросе портов если проверять с сайта 2ip то порт 80 и 443 должны быть открыты?

Comment: пробрасывать нужно в порты которые слушает nginx, т.е. в 80 и 443.

Comment: @AlexeyTen то есть при пробросе должен быть типа ip пк 80 80, и вторая строка ip пк 443 443?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147330/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-maks).

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поменять настройки в роутере на 80 80, 443 443 с ip моего пк

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/868602)

Comment: @Simon, это я сам ответил на свой вопрос, там довольно простая проблема была